# Android + Google API v2 + app not launched

Tags: android, google-maps, compiler-errors

I am creating a Google Map API v2 app, but I am having a problem visible in the LogCat and O do not know how to solve it can anyone help me?

I am using API Google 16. I have import the Google Play services and add to the project but I get this problem in the LogCat.

I will appreciate any help.

## main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        class="android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## LogCat

```
 04-12 07:54:02.176: E/Trace(1119): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-12 07:54:03.236: D/AndroidRuntime(1119): Shutting down VM
04-12 07:54:03.236: W/dalvikvm(1119): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapv2/com.example.googlemapv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at com.example.googlemapv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     ... 11 more
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment did not create a view.
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:303)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
04-12 07:54:03.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: There is a problem in line #7 of your XML. If it doesn't jump out at you, please post your XML and someone here will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this error line:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

Basiclly if you receive the `fragment/class not found error` then you problem is probably for lacking a good reference of the `google-play-services` library as `MapFragment`/`SupportMapFragment` is part of this library:

Check that yours `Android Dependencies` folder `(blue)` hold the `google-play-services` `(orange)` inside you will find the `com.google.android.gms.maps` package `(green)` that has the `MapFragment` class `(red)`:

[image]

If this is not the case you can check the first 3 steps of this blog post I wrote to get and idea on how to reference this package correctly:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: these packages exist in the android dependecies folder but still get and error .. i edit my question

Comment: rewmove this line: class="android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment"

Comment: thank you sir it is lunched now but i got another error that is display on the emulator **this app wont run unless  you update  Goole play  services** but its the latest update

Comment: this error is no related to the one you had before, you can accept this answer and take a look at this blog post I wrote on running google map in your emulator: http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527

Comment: i tried to install these 2 packages as you said but it says failure and these 2 packages already exist

Comment: Try to create a new AVD as described in the guide and install those packeages all over again.

Comment: but the target must be a google api not the normal one  right ??

Comment: as you see I'm using the Android API and if you use the Google's one this is the reason you receive the message it's already installed.

Comment: i did as you said and i get successful install but when i restart the AVD i get the **this app wont run unless you update Goole play services**